# Search/filter box for Views on separate page

Tags: 7, views, search

I am running the latest versions of Drupal 7 and [Views 3](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

I have a Views catalog with exposed filters for two different fields. What I would like to accomplish is to have a search box for the catalog on a different page (let's say the front page) with one field only - searching/filtering within either of the two fields. Upon submission, the user is taken to the catalog page with the results showing, and the exposed filters are free to be used again.

The only way I've been able to approximate this is to have a Global Combine fields filter running which is hidden on the catalog page, and utilized by a search filter box that I hard coded via a module. But the fact that the hidden combine field will actually have content in it once the page is loaded compromises the functionality of the visible exposed filters.

Is there a way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you know, in views there is one option called "EXposed form in Block"

Just enable this option then you can display the exposed filter block anywhere.

Hope this one helps you

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this option. My issue isn't really with getting the exposed filter block to appear on the front page. It is with having a unique search field that searches across multiple fields, but isn't one of the exposed filters (for reasons I elaborated on in the post).